# Internal Error occurred while analyzing this expression error in Android Studio Dolphin 2021.3.1

Tags: android, android-studio

After updating Android Studio all lines that get resources like String, Drawbles,... show this error:

> Internal Error occurred while analyzing this expression

What is wrong?

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-42886/Internal-Error-occurred-while-analyzing-this-expression issuetracker

Comment: I know it might create more problems than it fixes but updating to AS Canary(Electric Eel)fixed the issue without a change to build files.

Answer (score 3):

**Solution 1:**

You can try **File** -> **Invalidate Caches**.

**Solution 2:**

If this happened after update to `Dolphin 2021.3.1` than better to upgrade **Android Gradle Plugin**. It can be done by click on **Upgrade** in message **Project update recommended. Android Gradle Plugin can be upgraded.** which can appear in right bottom corner after project opening. In **Upgrade assistant** window check the variant **Upgrade** and click **Run selected steps**. Also you can open assistant manually: **Tools** -> **AGP Upgrade Assistant**.

After migration finished also some of your libraries versions will be updated. For me the version of `androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx` changed to `2.4.1`.

The version of `com.android.tools.build:gradle` can be updated to `7.3.0`.

```
   dependencies {
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
   }
```

Gradle wrapper can be updated to version `7.4`.

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-bin.zip
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
```

I also manually updated the version of `com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs` to `1.1.5` because I was facing error **Didn't find class "java.lang.Math8" on path: DexPathList** while launching my apps.

```
coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.1.5'
```

Answer (score 2):

Update your android gradle plugin to version 7.3.0. It helped in my case, I had the same issue on 7.0.3 version